# mapStateToProps state returns 'undefined' two times before fetching the data from firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux, react-redux, google-cloud-firestore

Component doesn't retrieve data from Firebase before it mounts.

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  return {
    products: state.firestore.ordered.products
  };
};
```

when I test for the props after it mounts...

```
componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.props);
}
```

The value of this.props.product is undefined.

---

If I console.log the state parameter inside mapStateToProps() I immediately get two console.logs of undefined and after a short while, I receive the actual array that I wanted.

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  const products2 = state.firestore.ordered.products;

  console.log(products2);  //returns 2 console logs of undefined,
  // after a second (after the component mounts) it gives me the data

  return {
    products: state.firestore.ordered.products
  };
};
```

---

The reason why that is an issue is when I want to render the component using the data from the Firebase.

```
<div className="item-render-space">
          {products
            .filter(
              eachProduct =>
                eachProduct.landingPageCategory.indexOf(this.props.category) >
                -1
            )
            .map(eachProduct => (
              <div className="each-product" key={eachProduct.id}>
                <Link to={"/product/" + eachProduct.id}>
                  <img src={eachProduct.image} alt="#" />
                  <p className="product-price">{eachProduct.price}</p>
                  <p className="product-name">
                    {nameShortener(eachProduct.name)}
                  </p>
                </Link>
              </div>
            ))}
        </div>
```

I get an error screen because the variable "products" is undefined because The data from the firebase hasn't reached the component when it started rendering.

How to fix this issue?!

EDIT: Here is the rootReducer:

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  firestore: firestoreReducer, //connects to firestore
  live: liveReducer, //used locally for opening bootstrap modals
  products: productsReducer, //previous products store before implementing Firestore
  firebase: firebaseReducer //connects to firebase
});
```

Comment: Conditional rendering (this.props.products && this.props.products.length > 0) or default to empty array `[]`. This isn't unique to react-redux or firebase, this is a common issue with retrieving data async.

Comment: how to default to an empty array?

Comment: How would you usually default a value in **your** redux store? Also you could consider `defaultProps` or simply using a logical operator such as `||` in `mapStateToProps()` or even in `render()`. There's a lot of ways, it depends on your application. Share your reducer perhaps to more information about your store structure.

Comment: I'm quite new to redux and firebase, Do i need to create a reparate function in the component? I tried doing that but failed miserably. I tried creating an if(product !== undefined) but nothing I tried worked. I'll share the reducer 1 sec

Comment: Share your reducer please and what your `initialState` looks like for more assistance. At minimum try the following `{products && products.length > 0 &&`. Also review the following https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html.

Comment: Is this how its supposed to look like?        {products && products.length > 0 && (
          <div className="item-render-space">
            {products
              .filter(

Comment: `<div className="item-render-space">{products && products.length > 0 && products.filter(/* your logic *).map(/* your logic */ }</div>`. Here is a simplified example https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-qyyzpi

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much! My last problem was in the database itself :D Have a wonderful day!

Comment: I created an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [conditional rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html) to avoid attempting to execute Array.prototype.filter() and Array.prototype.map() on `undefined`. The following would check for `products` to be truthy and have a `length` of greater than 0:

```
<div className="item-render-space">
  {products && products.length > 0 && products
    .filter(
      eachProduct =>
        eachProduct.landingPageCategory.indexOf(this.props.category) >
        -1
    )
    .map(eachProduct => (
      <div className="each-product" key={eachProduct.id}>
        <Link to={"/product/" + eachProduct.id}>
          <img src={eachProduct.image} alt="#" />
          <p className="product-price">{eachProduct.price}</p>
          <p className="product-name">
            {nameShortener(eachProduct.name)}
          </p>
        </Link>
      </div>
    ))}
</div>
```

Hopefully that helps!